# Joined object not acting as its parent with a Curve Modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

[image]
I added this long band on the side of the main object, but when I apply a Curve modifier on both, the band acts weird... I don't understand why. They now have the same origin since they are joined.

Comment: Are they joined (ctrl+j) or parented (ctrl+p) ? In other words, are they one unique Object or two distinct Objects ?

Comment: They are joined ctrl+J

Comment: Does the band have enough subdivisions, so it can curve ? Try adding some loopcuts along it.

Comment: Could you upload the blend file? Please use this link for that https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb now. Yeah that was it... Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The band doesn't have enough subdivisions to  be able to curve. Try adding some loopcuts along it.

Comment: Hi. If you need to ask a question or clarify details this should be done as a comment.

Comment: That's what I did and it answered the question, so I formulated it as an answer. But you're right and I will edit the answer in that sense.